# Car suggests shifting gears too early

Tags: vw, diesel, turbocharger

I own a 2014 Volkswagen Passat 2.0 TDI Bluemotion. It is a 6 speed manual transmission. I understand that it is a car tuned for economy. But it still asks me to shift too early.

For example if I'm at 1800 - 2000 rpm at 70 km/h in 4th gear, it will ask me to shift upto 6th. When i shift into 6th the engine is barely at 1200 - 1300 rpm, which I imagine is going to lug the engine pretty badly as it is a turbocharged and the engine doesn't get boost until 1600 rpm.

So, my question is whether i should actually take the car's suggestions for shifting gears, or listen to myself and try to keep the engine in the powerband as much as possible ignoring the early shifts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember, the gearshift indicator is a "trick" used to cover the EU economy tests and guilty of being useless in pretty much every car manufacturer unless you are on a super economy run

Comment: I've not driven the Passat, but generally, the gear shift indicators on newer cars prompt you to shift based on your acceleration, not just RPMs. So if you're accelerating slowly, it will prompt you to shift sooner,  but if you're flooring it, the prompt will come later.

Comment: Remark - nope, that wasn't part of their sneaky tricks at all. The indicator is just an indicator. It has nothing to do with the engine management tricks that changed emissions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is suggesting shifting up early as "it is tuned for economy" - it is not trying to get you to speed quickly. It is trying to be economic with fuel.

If you follow the guidance on the dash (remember it doesn't expect you to shift at the moment the indicator appears, but at some point soon after that) then you will gently accelerate, and not go into boost. (using the turbo does cost in terms of fuel economy)

If you want to accelerate faster, and stay in each gear longer you will get to top speed faster but use more fuel in the process.

As an example, if I'm gentle and short shift in my Litchfield (changing up around 1200rpm), I can average around 35mpg. Going for performance (changing up at 7500rpm) I average 8 mpg. In the later cass I get to 60 in 4 seconds, as opposed to more than double that when I accelerate gently.

So the answer is: It's up to you. How do you wish to drive?